# group list of object based on date in rxjva2 android

Tags: android, group-by, rx-java

I have this following model:

```
{
"account" : {
    "accountName": "Complete Access",
    "accountNumber": "062005 1709 5888",
    "available": 226.76,
    "balance": 246.76
},
"transactions": [{
    "id": "44e5b2bc484331ea24afd85ecfb212c8",
    "effectiveDate": "20/07/2017",
    "description": "Kaching TFR from JOHN CITIZEN<br/>xmas donation",
    "amount": 12.00
}, {
    "id": "1506aeeb8c3a699b1e3c87db03156428",
    "effectiveDate": "20/07/2017",
    "description": "Wdl ATM CBA ATM CIRCULAR QUAY STATION NSW 221092 AUS",
    "amount": -200.00,
    "atmId": "129382"
}]
```

}

I wanna groupd them based on effectiveDate on Rxjava but pretty fresh on it...could you please help to do os. thanks much

my failed effort:

```
                        Observable.fromIterable(transactionsViewModel.getTransactions())
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .groupBy(transaction -> transaction.getEffectiveDate())
                    .flatMap(grouped -> {
                        groupedTransactionMap.put(grouped.getKey(),grouped.toList().blockingGet());
                        return grouped;
                    })
                    .subscribe(v -> System.out.println(v));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close! This might help you a bit:

```
Observable.fromIterable(transactionsViewModel.getTransactions())
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .groupBy(transaction -> transaction.getEffectiveDate())
          .flatMapSingle(grouped -> grouped.collect(ArrayList::new, List::add))
          ...
```

That should group all the same dates and put them into lists, then it will emit each list. You should get *n* lists where *n* is the number of distinct dates you have. So, for your example, you should only get one list to emit with two entries.

Edit: if you want a mapping out of that, you can continue to transform the stream as follows:

```
Observable.fromIterable(transactionsViewModel.getTransactions())
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .groupBy(transaction -> transaction.getEffectiveDate())
          .flatMapSingle(grouped -> grouped.collect((Callable<ArrayList<Transaction>>) ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add))
          .toMap(transactions -> transactions.get(0).getEffectiveDate())
          ...
```

This will, however, become a `Single<Map<Date,Transaction>>` instead of an `Observable`.

Comment: thanks much for your answer. How can I get out something like that hashmap from rxjava? I feel I shouldn't fill hashmap inside flatmap like now...

Comment: you can perform further transformations on that stream to turn it into a hashmap after the data has been grouped. I'll update the answer